# How can I make a reactionCollector on a remove event work?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

So, I am working on a discord bot. Here I start a `reactionCollector`. When a reaction is collected, it does something, and when the reaction is removed, it should do something else.

```
await message.channel.send(embed)
  then(async function (message) {
    await message.react('⚔')

    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return reaction.emoji.name === '⚔' && user.id != 705462496646922311
    };
    collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter);

    collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
      // Do something.
    });

    collector.on('remove', (reaction, user) => {
      // Do something.
    });
  })
  .catch(function() {
    message.channel.send('Error while adding the reaction. Try again')
  });
```

The remove event never gets called. Does anyone know why this happen? Where did I do a mistake?

Comment: I'm pretty sure on the second line, it should be
`.then()` instead of `then()`

Comment: It was a copy and paste error! I'm sorrry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your [ReactionCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector) fire `dispose` and `remove` events you have to enable `dispose` in the [CollectorOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorOptions) of your [ReactionCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector) just like that :

```js
collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { dispose: true });
```

Also, be carefull when manipulating IDs ([Snowflakes](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake)), they are always type of String. In your code you try to see if `user.id` is not equal to a number (really big number by the way!) so don't forget to surround IDs with quotes.

```js
return reaction.emoji.name === '⚔' && user.id != "705462496646922311";
```