# How to use remove event with ReactionCollector?

Tags: discord.js

[How can I make a reactionCollector on a remove event work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61858152/how-can-i-make-a-reactioncollector-on-a-remove-event-work)
Similar to this question, but the solution listed was not my solution.

```
msg.channel.send("Hello World")
    .then(async function (message) {
         await message.react('✅')
         const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return reaction.emoji.name === '✅'
         };
   
         const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, {time: time, dispose: true});

         collector.on('remove', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
          console.log("React removed")
         });
   
         collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
              console.log("React added")
         });

    });
```

The linked question solution was to add `dispose: true` to the collectorOptions, this hasn't worked for me. "React removed" is never logged.

Answer (score 0):

Remove is only supported in v12+. I was using v11.